# Python unit test TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'MagicMock' and 'int'

Tags: python, unit-testing, pyspark, mocking

I am trying to mock a dataframe creation in python using MockMagic() but looks like, some part of the code is failing due to unsupported comparison in MagicMock when called from unit test function.

This is my testcase.py code

```
sys.modules["pyspark.sql"] = MagicMock()

def test_process_batch():
    df = (
        [
            (1, "foo"),
            (2, "bar"),
        ],
        ["id", "label"]
    )
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
    spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(df)

    process_batch(spark_df, "123")
    assert True
```

In the main program, the code for `process_batch()` contains a line to compare the dataframe count to a number like below.

```
def process_batch(data_frame, batchId):
    """Process streamed batch dataframe"""

    if (data_frame.count() > 0):
     ...
```

Unit test failed with following error.

```
[CPython38-test] =================================== FAILURES ===================================
[CPython38-test] ______________________________ test_process_batch ______________________________
[CPython38-test] 
[CPython38-test]     def test_process_batch():
[CPython38-test]         df = (
[CPython38-test]             [
[CPython38-test]                 (1, "foo"),
[CPython38-test]                 (2, "bar"),
[CPython38-test]             ],
[CPython38-test]             ["id", "label"]
[CPython38-test]         )
[CPython38-test]         from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
[CPython38-test]         spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
[CPython38-test]         spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
[CPython38-test]     
[CPython38-test] >       process_batch(spark_df, "123")
[CPython38-test] 
[CPython38-test] test/test_cia_optics_ingestion_glue_spark_streaming.py:54: 
[CPython38-test] _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
[CPython38-test] 
[CPython38-test] data_frame = <MagicMock name='mock.SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate().createDataFrame()' id='140188327287056'>
[CPython38-test] batchId = '123'
[CPython38-test] 
[CPython38-test]     def process_batch(data_frame, batchId):
[CPython38-test]         """Process streamed batch dataframe"""
[CPython38-test]     
[CPython38-test] >       if (data_frame.count() > 0):
[CPython38-test] E       TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'MagicMock' and 'int'
[CPython38-test]
```

Can you please guide me how to overcome this situation ?

Comment: Sounds like `spark_df` is a `MagicMock`.  Maybe do `spark_df.count.return_value = something` before you call `process_batch`?

Comment: Perhaps this can help you?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50242955/comparing-integer-to-magicmock-not-working-inside-unittest-in-python

Comment: You are basically mocking everything, because you mock `pyspark.sql` - everything you get (`spark`, `spark_df`) are mocks, and it does not matter what `df` you pass. From the code, it is not clear to me what you actually want to test.

Answer (score 0):

You can mock the `count()` method as well, as pointed by Samwise: `spark_df.count.return_value = 10`. The complete working code will look like:

```py
import sys
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

sys.modules["pyspark.sql"] = MagicMock()


def process_batch(data_frame, batchId):
    """Process streamed batch dataframe"""

    if data_frame.count() > 0:
        ...


def test_process_batch():
    df = ([(1, "foo"), (2, "bar"), ], ["id", "label"])
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
    spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
    spark_df.count.return_value = 10

    process_batch(spark_df, "123")
    assert True
```